# Append JSON element to a list

Tags: python, json

```
x = []
a = {'sample': True}
x.append(a)
a["sample"] = False
x.append(a)
print(x)
```

The current result is `[{'sample': False}, {'sample': False}]`.

I need the response to be `[{'sample': True}, {'sample': False}]`.

I've tried `x.update({"sample": False})`; same effect.

Comment: You change a ["sample"] to false before you append it, so you will never get your desired output

Comment: PS.. this is not a JSON Element, is a dictionary with a single entry.

Comment: @JeffUK I append a to x before change it....

Comment: @JeffUK this is just sample, to replicate the issue

Comment: When you do `x.append(a)` you are appending a *reference* to the `dict`.  So, when you change `a`. you are also changing the element in the list.

Comment: Why not just do x.append({'sample':False}) instead of using 'a' at all? Why do you need to copy the dictionary before you edit it at all? these seems to be adding unnecessary complication

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are appending the 'pointer' (python object) of dictionary, not a copy.

You can try:

```
def copyof(dico): return {**dico}
a = {'a':True}
x.append(copyof(a))
```

It will be Ok

Comment: Note that this is a shallow copy. If there's any deeper nesting it'll require a deep copy.

Comment: He didn't need deepcopy

Comment: We don't know since the OP says this is sample code. The real code might have a more complex object. It's worth mentioning.

Comment: import copy
x.append(copy.deepcopy(a))